# Not able to boot 16.04 LTS in dual boot with window 7 UEFI mode

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Initially I am not getting the option to install ubuntu along side window 7. So I again installed window 7 in UEFI mode and now able to get this option. But after installing ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside window 7, I am not able to boot ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I tried ubuntu boot-repair tool but still getting the same problem. Can anyone help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the link to the Summary Report that Boot-Repair runs.

Comment: Please either do as oldfred suggests or run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

I have `win7` at side `Ubuntu 16.04`

If you want to,too. You should first **install ubuntu**, then **install windows**.

And now your ubuntu boot is damaged by win boot **but** it has nice tools that name of is `boot-repair-disk`

After installing **windows**, then by `boot-repair-disk` go to Ubuntu and repair its boots.

> No need to internet and easy to use

:)

Source : https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/ (Write on cd or flash boot)

Size : about 700 mp

Answer (score -1):

If you have secure boot enabled in the bios then it will not load the grub bootloader and will always boot into Windows.

You are going to want to boot into bios to turn it off. It is different for each computer however it's usually something like F2 or F8 (or another combination of the Fbuttons). 
You should have a menu for "Boot" at the top of the Bios screen. Then look for the boot mode option (should say UEFI). Usually underneath of that is the Secure Boot option. Switch it to "disabled" and then save and exit the bios, after reboot you should see grub menu.

**NOTE**: Some Bios Software needs an administrator password to be set in the Bios in order to disable Secure Boot. You will have to find that setting and set an administrator password. Do not choose the "Require password on boot" option and you should only need to enter the password whenever you want to enter the Bios settings.

Comment: Ubuntu is compatible with Secure Boot. Although there are occasional firmware bugs and other problems with Secure Boot, your answer is far too broad. Furthermore, if the problem *were* caused by Secure Boot, it's very unlikely that the Ubuntu installation medium would boot at all, so such a problem would not produce the symptoms reported.

Comment: I was just trying to help with what what worked for me. I could boot from usb but after installation it wouldn't boot into grub until I disabled secure boot. So I apologize if it was too broad in your standards however if it was the exact same issue I was having (which from the OP it sounded very similar) then disabling secure boot works and will boot into grub.

Comment: Your problem was most likely an issue of boot mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI), not of Secure Boot per se.